# docusign - radioGroupTabs not working (locked out) in a compositeTemplate

Tags: node.js, docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I am trying to add a pdf with form fields document to a docusign envelope using inlineTemplates, everything is good, docusign is able to parse the textTabs, signHereTabs etc, but the problem is radioGroupTabs, when I send the envelope, these fields are locked.
The only way I got those fields unlocked/fillable is by assigning first signer as defaultRecipient.

```
tabs: {
    textTabs: [
      {
        tabLabel: `ESIG_ADVISORDOC_SIGNER1_\\*`,
      },
    ],
    radioGroupTabs: [
      {
        groupName: `ESIG_ADVISORDOC_SIGNER1_TCP_ADD_REM`, // didn't work
      },
      {
        groupName: `ESIG_ADVISORDOC_SIGNER1_\\*`, // didn't work
      }
    ]
   }
```

I tried multiple things, example use tabLabel in place of groupName for the radioGroupTabs etc etc, nothing worked. Tried with a wildcard, tried with the exact fieldName, tried with both.

Can someone please suggest a solution?

Comment: @Inbar Gazit any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after two days of trials and errors, found that we need to pass locked: false in the radios attribute.

```
tabs: {
    textTabs: [
      {
        tabLabel: `ESIG_ADVISORDOC_SIGNER1_\\*`,
      },
    ],
    radioGroupTabs: [
      {
        groupName: `ESIG_ADVISORDOC_SIGNER1_\\*`,
        radios: [
         { locked: 'false' }
        ]
      }
    ]
   }
```

Docusign should be better with their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Tabs have an optional field `locked`. I believe the default for that value should be false but you could try explicitly setting `locked` to false to force the tabs to be editable.

Comment: Didn't work, I even tried giving optional: false, also tried by providing recipientId and documentId, nothing seems to work.